# Login without Login Page

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle-adf

I have java ADF Web Application , and its in our company and we use secure network
so can i Authenticate the users depend on there login to windows ... if we can get the user Who login to the windows we can do this

i try some commands in java 
like
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
System.getenv("USERNAME");
but all give me server user not client

and i try

request.getRemoteUser()  ... it always return null until i do SSO login 
and i don't need SSO cause the user is login by his account to Windows

Can any one Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like the user logged in to your application based on his logging into a windows workstation, then you are basically asking for Single Sign-on (SSO). In that case, request.getRemoteUser() would be the right method to call.

You could also inspect the request headers and find the header that is populated with the username and then fetch it's value via request.getHeader("USER_HEADER_NAME").

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve, but as far as I know, you need to setup Single Sign-on to your application if you want access to it without another authentication.